# Synchronization Block

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized, java-threads

I am new to threads in Java and hence have this doubt. I read that a **'synchronized non-static method block'** allows only one thread to enter the block (for one instance of non-static block, of-course). However it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?
Look at the following code.

```
class A extends Thread
{
    public void run() 
    {
        B.b.add();
    }
}

class B
{
    static B b=new B();
    int i;
    public synchronized void add()
    {
        i++;
    }
}

public class Sample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            new A().start();
        }
        System.out.println(B.b.i);
    }
}
```

Comment: wait, does it have something to do with cache write policy? Because I expected a result '10' to be printed, but the result is random, from 0 to 9.

Comment: Sorry, got it. The main thread is printing the value before the value is incremented by all the threads (since executed in parallel). How can I print the value after all the threads have completed execution?

Comment: If you want to wait for all threads you have to join them after the loop, see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()

Answer (score 2):

One problem here is that your main thread doesn't wait for the other threads to finish before it tries to retrieve the result. Using Thread#join works if you want to wait for a single thread, but here we want to wait for all 10. Modifying the program to use CountDownLatch makes the main thread wait until all the threads it created are finished.

Another problem is that the updated value of i isn't guaranteed to be visible. JVM implementations differ about how aggressively they perform optimizations (like delaying refreshes of cached values, or reordering bytecode) that may make the changes to i not visible to the main thread. Adding a synchronized method on the same lock as the add method to fetch the value of i fixes the visibility issue.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

class A extends Thread {
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    public A(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }    
    @Override public void run() {
        B.b.add();
        latch.countDown();
    }
}

class B {
    static B b=new B();
    int i;
    public synchronized void add() {
        i++;
    }
    public synchronized int getI() { 
        return i;
    }
}

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(10);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            new A(latch).start();
        }
        latch.await();     
        System.out.println(B.b.getI());
    }
}
```